# S-curve Graph Mirror

Tags: mirror-symmetry

I have an s-curve equation that uses cosine. Any trigonometric function is allowed but I can't use exponential or logarithmic equations as they don't perform to what is required. The cosine equation works great for certain settings but for others, I need to mirror it using the existing coordinate points; I need to invert the ess while using the same coordinate points. I've tried a few ways but I can't have the equation switching its location to a different quadrant. The included image, or link, shows the equation, the current s-curve in red, and the needed s-curve in green. Please help me to find the variation of the current equation or a different trigonometric equation that will enable this. Thank you. Gary

[S-curve equation and graph, current s-curve in red, needed s-curve in green](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VePgd.png)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Hi Community. I don't know how to get any more detailed than it is already. Thank you for trying.

Comment: Hi Community. I still can't understand what more details you are looking for as you will not tell me. I posted the exact same post on ptc.com and I got the correct response the next day. The two regulars who helped me did not ask for more details. I wish you well. Gary